# Can I import code from another folder in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm using an scripting engine that uses delphi and I can't change the compiler options. I want to know if I can import code from another directory just with some code like `unit '..\myUnit'`. The other option I have would be to flatten the directories.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this without moving files around is too use Project | Add to Project in the IDE to add these 'other' units to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In the uses clause of the project source file (and only there, i.e. in the file that you see when you choose Project > View Source), a unit name may be followed by the reserved word in and the name of a source file, for example:

```
uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  MainUnit in 'MainUnit.pas',
  MyFirstExtraUnit in 'C:\Extras\MyFirstExtraUnit.pas',
  MySecondExtraUnit in '..\..\MySecondExtraUnit.pas';
```

Paths can be absolute or relative.

This is described in Embarcadero's docwiki at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#Unit_References_and_the_Uses_Clause

The same effect is achieved via the Delphi IDE by choosing Project > Add to Project...